# how to make DropBox in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am a Fresher Developer in iPhone .
I am working on DropBox Demo Example.
I have no any idea about DropBox.
I am Working in Xcode 4.5.
So, Can anybody share dropbox documentation and dropbox example ?

i refer [this](https://github.com/schwa/dropbox-iphone-sdk) github example. But that not work it can give an error.

Thank x in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Start by downloading the iPhone dropbox SDK, Then follow the tutorial at the Dropbox Developers Getting Started Docs. Link Below.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

Next time google it and do some research yourself, important skill to learn for university.

Comment: i want a good example. i am work on fresher level.